# VBA Excel find and replace character limit

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find

I'm trying to replace a small sentence with a long sentence in Excel.
I know it works as when I try to replace with just a few characters it does it. But it doesn't like a long sentence. I can type a long sentence so I know the cell can cope with the amount of characters.
Is there a hard character limit? And if so can this be changed? If it helps, I only want to search in Column U.

This is my code (excuse the first part as I recorded a macro and it kept my cell selection in):

```vb
Sub FindReplaceWords()
    '
    ' FindReplaceWords Macro
    '

    '
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "That they were born this year - First Christmas!"
    Range("M11").Select

    Cells.Replace What:="That they were born this year - First Christmas!", _
        Replacement:="My elves are hard at work making sure we have something extra-special waiting for you under the tree this year - although nothing can compare to receiving such a precious gift as yourself. You'll be able to enjoy so many wonderful things as time passes: learning how to crawl and talk, discovering new places and people; but being part of a loving family will always be one of life's greatest treasures.  On behalf of myself and all my elves here at The North Pole we wish all good tidings during this festive season, hope lots of joy abounds throughout your home and many happy memories await both today & tomorrow!", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

    Cells.Replace What:="That they started nursery this year", Replacement:= _
        "I just wanted to take a moment and congratulate you on starting nursery! How exciting it must be for you to learn new things and make friends this year. I know that it can be a bit daunting starting something new, but don't worry – everyone is so kind at the nursery and they will look after you until pick-up time. You're going to have such an amazing time there.”, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2 

    Cells.Replace What:="That they started preschool this year", Replacement:= _
        "I wanted to take this opportunity to congratulate you on such a big milestone. Starting preschool can be a little scary but it also means so much growth and learning ahead for you! I'm sure by now you've been very busy with all the new things that come along with starting school. You must be meeting lots of new friends, playing games and make lots of great art and craft projects", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
        FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

    Cells.Replace What:="That they started primary school this year", _
        Replacement:="This year has been a special one for you as you started primary school! Primary school is such an important milestone and I’m so proud of you for taking on the challenge. You must have learned so many new things this year; about numbers and letters, about friendship and kindness, about all sorts of interesting things.", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase _
        :=False, FormulaVersion:=xlReplaceFormula2

End Sub
```

I get runtime error 13, mismatch type.

Comment: In your code you have quote like this ” chr(148) instead of that " chr(34) (not the same).  just replace them

Comment: The reason for the 'type mismatch' error is that the [Range.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range.replace) method does not have a 'FormulaVersion' property ... delete that (from each `Replace`) and try again.

Comment: @JohnM Excel 365 has argument `FormulaVersion` althought it isn't listed on online document.

Comment: Fair enough ... good old MS keeping their documentation up to date, I guess!

Answer (score 0):

There's a 255 character limit.  If you run this it will break at n = 256.

```
Sub FindReplaceLimit()
    Dim n As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
    For n = 1 To 1000
        .Cells(1, 1) = "x"
       .Cells(1, 1).Replace "x", String(n, "x")
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

If you replace the string in vba instead of using the cell formula, the length is the cell's character limit of 32,767.  "s" can be longer than 32,767, but only the first 32,767 characters will be copied to the cell.

```
Sub FindReplaceLimit2()
    Dim s As String
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1) = "x"
        s = .Cells(1, 1)
        s = Replace(s, "x", String(32767, "x"))
       .Cells(1, 1) = s
    End With 
End Sub
```